# Web API: multipart/form-data post not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, streaming, fiddler

I've read every internet post on this and I still don't know what I'm doing wrong.  From `Fiddler`, I'm trying to post multiple items and it's not working. I'm not able to post a `.jpeg`, but a `.txt` is no working. First requests to the method are successful, but all subsequent requests aren't and will generate "*Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete*" or "*An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending*".  If I just send text entries in the parts/boundaries, it will only see the first one - the others are ignored

**Web API**

```
[HttpPost]
[MimeMultipart]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync()
     {
      var uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");
      Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
      var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadPath);
      // THIS IS WHERE THE ERRORS HAPPEN
      await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
      // NEVER HAS A NAME(S),, EVEN WHEN NO ERROR
      var localFileName = provider.FileData.Select(multiPartData => multiPartData.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var stream in provider.Contents)
        {
            var fileBytes = stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent("Successful upload", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"text/html");
        }
      // omitted code
```

**Fidder Headers**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:1703
Content-Length: 3199
```

**Fiddler Body**

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description" 
Content-Type: text

the_text_is_here
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="today.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\loser\Desktop\today.txt*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468-
```

Should I use a different `content-type`?  I'm dying over here.

Comment: I don't know whether it's _the_ issue, but you do need to await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), which you aren't doing.

Comment: @sellotape..Right I added it, but not the problem